Search Result to Link to a Specific Page
I'm currently working on my online store and I would like to use my search results as a product filter, sending people to specific pages intead of showing general seach results.
For example:

Someone clicks the search icon and types "Metallica" or "Iron Maiden" (or any other band TBH)
I want the search result to send the user to a specific Metallica page, or Iron Maiden page, so I can actully get rid of product filtering.

Is this possible?
My search is currently sending people to a default search result page, showing products related to the specified keyword. Like... Normal.
I would love to know how to send people to specific pages, so I can create personalized pages for each band following my main Store page layout.
Would you mind giving me a hand?
Thank you very much!
I appreciate your time and effort!
I'm curretly trying to figure it out, but with no success.
Best regards,

Sounds like you'll have to code something custom here.
I like the idea TBH - but I haven't seen anything like this in WordPress before.
As I see it, you'll have to make a custom SQL query, or maybe even use get_terms() (Function description here) to achieve your goal.
You would have to:

Hook into the search - maybe using the template_redirect() (Hook description here) action - I've found a Stack Exchange answer on how to do this here. It gives you an idea on how to do this part.

Now you'll have to get your search-term, and using something like below, to get the URL for the specific term:


$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'name__like' => 'SEARCH_TERM_HERE',
    'fields'     => 'all',
    'hide_empty' => true,
);

$terms = get_terms($args);


Lastly use get_term_link() (Function description here) to get the URL of the term (if any term is found, that is).

This is only a quick outline on how I would start approaching this. I'm sure it can be optimized - but this is definitely how I would start off. You should also make sure that it redirects the user to the normal search-result page if no terms match the search term.

Hey, WPTricksDK!
Man, thank you very much for your time! You make coding look just as beautiful as it is! I appreciate very much your effort! I loved how you liked the idea, as I also did..! Just occured to me when I was looking for my products on my website, and now I feel the native search can be powerful.
Just to note, I found some plugins that actually address the issue, but I love how you made it easy to visualize. Maybe the plugins can be easier to achieve this through what they call "Redirects", but I'm in the mood of implementing it natively.

Just in case anyone else is looking to make you native website search this powerful, there are some plugins I found that address this issue, they are:

WPSearch Premium
Relevanssi Premium

Unfortunately, they are all paid. The free version doesn't allow us to use the tool.
